# htaccess restrict folder access based on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a web setup where there are multiple sites under one directory... and one media folder containing images for each site...

```
www.domain1.com/media/domain1.com/
www.domain2.com/media/domain2.com/
```

As you can see domain1.com's media can be accessed from domain2 e.g. `www.domain2.com/media/domain1.com/`
and vice versa...

I want to restrict domain1 to access `/media/domain2.com/` folder can it be done via htaccess file?

my idea was to somehow read the domain name and match it with the directory its trying to access...

or

alternatively can redirect all requests in media folder to a php script that can do the matching...?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to do this in a shared hosting environment where I can't use virtual hosts, and it's painful!

Answer (score 0):

Use VirtualHost for each domain and specify DocumentRoot for them, it will also remove the /media/domainN/ from URL.

If you want to perserve the document root for some reason, try using this in each VirtualHost directive:

```
<Directory "full/path/to/media/domain1.com">
deny from all
</Directory>
```

and vice-versa for domain2.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, the problem is apache config file is generated on the fly and there's only one host entry for all websites...  
`
    <VirtualHost *>  
        ServerAdmin aqeel@xxx.com  
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts  
        ServerName domain1.com  
        ServerAlias domain2.com  
        ServerAlias domain3.com  
        .....  
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts>  
           AllowOverride All  
        </Directory>  
    </VirtualHost>  
`

Comment: sorry am not familiar with the formatting here... my comment looks messed up!